# How can BLS Data be extracted into Excel via Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python (zero coding / data science experience) and looking for help with a python code that will retrieve, in Excel format, a workbook that contains the number of new jobs created in every USA MSA at Year End for each of the last 10 years. If possible, the script would also include the total number of employed persons for that time period in the same MSA. This way, I can track the percentage change in employment.

I tried using Chat GPT but I don't think I know how to "ask the question" correctly yet.

Comment: In the assumption that you're ready to put in the work (and not simply looking for someone else to do the work for you): have you found a source for a history the number of new jobs created in every USA MSA? Or for the number of employed persons? A script is not going to find that data for you, you'll have to do the research yourself.

Comment: Yes, BLS has the data for jobs. US Census Bureau has the data for employed persons. I could pull dozens of separate excel files to manually do this via copy and paste. But, I am assuming there is a more professional way to do so.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Well, doing this with 0 coding experience is quite a journey, but the issue at hand provides an accessible opportunity to learn coding. Your question is very broad, so I can only provide you with rough steps. When you run into issues with any of these steps you can ask a specific question (after confirming that the same question had not be answered before).

1. Install Python by following one of many tutorials (e.g. [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-python-windows-10))
2. Install an IDE to edit your code in, e.g. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder).
3. Create a virtual environment by following one of many tutorials (e.g. [this one](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/))
4. In that virtual environment install the `pandas` and `xlsxwriter`. The first is useful in working with tabular data, the second is needed for exports to Excel.
5. Read and understand the [API examples on the BLS site](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_python.htm)
6. Now you can rewrite the examples using the `seriesid` for the datasets you're interested in, reformat it into a table and then export to an Excel file.

Here I show how to do step 6 using the [first API example on the BLS site](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_python.htm):

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# Get the data from the BLS API
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
# Here the seriesid's and year ranges are defined.
# CUUR0000SA0 is the CPI for All Urban Consumers
# SUUR0000SA0 is the Chained CPI for All Urban Consumers, U.S. city average
series = ["CUUR0000SA0", "SUUR0000SA0"]
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": series, "startyear": "2011", "endyear": "2014"})
p = requests.post(
    "https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/", data=data, headers=headers
)
json_data = json.loads(p.text)

# Transform it into a dataframe (which is a kind of table)
df0 = pd.DataFrame(json_data["Results"]["series"][0])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_data["Results"]["series"][1])

# Expand the single data column into separate columns and append it to the seriesID
df0 = pd.concat([df0.seriesID, pd.json_normalize(df0.data)], axis=1)
df1 = pd.concat([df1.seriesID, pd.json_normalize(df1.data)], axis=1)

# Place everything in a single dataframe
df = pd.concat([df0, df1])

# Write to Excel
df.to_excel(r"./output.xlsx", index=False)
```